# Does Java 8 with Bouncy Castle as security provider support X25519 namedgroup?

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, tls1.3, x25519

I am using java 8 (1.8.0_332-b09) and bouncy castle as security provider for establishing a TLS 1.3 connection.

As part of handshake, Client Hello in packetcapture shows the supported namedgroups as follows :
secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072,ffdhe4096.

However, I want to enable support for X25519 namedgroups. I tried using system property System.setProperty("jdk.tls.namedGroups", "x25519,secp256r1,secp384r1,secp521r1");
in client code. However, in the packet capture, it is showing secp256r1, secp384r1 and secp521r1 only.